# Imperative command for creating job and cronjob in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, cron, jobs, kubectl

Is this a valid imperative command for creating job?

```
kubectl create job my-job --image=busybox
```

I see this in https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands. But the command is not working. I am getting error as bellow:

> Error: unknown flag: --image

What is the correct imperative command for creating job?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren’t using the more standard kubectl apply? The older style is not really recommended anymore.

Comment: I have not tried it.I found this command in kubernetes.io and its not working.Hence checking..

Comment: As it's not recommended way of handling things inside Kubernetes I need to ask you which version of Kubernetes you tried this command on?

Answer (score 4):

Try this one

```
kubectl create cronjob my-job  --schedule="0,15,30,45 * * * *" --image=busy-box
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have should work, though it not recommended as an approach anymore. I would check what version of `kubectl` you have, and possibly upgrade it if you aren't using the latest.

That said, the more common approach these days is to write a YAML file containing the Job definition and then run `kubectl apply -f myjob.yaml` or similar. This file-driven approach allowed for more natural version control, editing, review, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Using correct value for --restart field on "kubectl run" will result run command to create an deployment or job or cronjob

```
--restart='Always': The restart policy for this Pod.  Legal values [Always, OnFailure, Never].  If set to 'Always'
a deployment is created, if set to 'OnFailure' a job is created, if set to 'Never', a regular pod is created. For the
latter two --replicas must be 1.  Default 'Always', for CronJobs `Never`.
```

Use "kubectl run" for creating basic kubernetes job using imperatively command as below

`master $ kubectl run nginx --image=nginx --restart=OnFailure --dry-run -o yaml > output.yaml`

Above should result an "output.yaml" as below example, you can edit this yaml for advance configurations as needed and create job by "kubectl create -f output.yaml or if you just need basic job then remove --dry-run option from above command and you will get basic job created.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: nginx
  name: nginx
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        run: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: nginx
        resources: {}
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
status: {}
```

Comment: Hi, is this info valid for `v1.19.0` ?